# replace markdown heading to starts

Tags: regex

I have a markdown file with five levels of heading

```
#  heading 1
##
...
##### heading 5
```

How could convert them to

```
* 
** 
....
*****
```

with one try of regex expression.

I get it done with five tries of replacement?

Answer (score 2):

How about like this:

```
#[^\n#]*
```

`#` followed by any amount of characters that are [not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `#` or newline.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/avOIVD/1)

For chaining from linestart, [use `\G`](https://regex101.com/r/avOIVD/2) anchor [if supported](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) by your regex lib (Python: [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)).